# Format a cell in each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I changed the color and other things of cell `M1` in a worksheet. I need to do the same thing in all worksheets of my workbook (the same cell in all the sheets).

There are about 40 sheets so I need to program this task with VBA.

I recorded the procedure but don't know how to write the code to do this in all the worksheets.

The code I recorded:

```
Sub Macro_1() '' Macro_1 Macro ' Change the look of a cell in all worksheets '  

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub
```

Comment: show the code that you have so far. it may be as simple as adding a `FOR EACH` loop over the sheets collection.

Comment: You don't need VBA code for that.  You can select the first sheet, hold shift and select the last sheet to select all sheets between first and last and then just format the cell - it will apply the format to all selected sheets.

Comment: I know that its simple and easy, I'm not proud of this question (jaja), but I need to learn this fast as possible.

Comment: This is the complete code that I recorded:

Comment: One way to shorten the code is to look for default values.  For example, your first `With...End With` block of code centers your text with `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter`.  By default it already appears aligned to the bottom, without merging the cells, wrapping the text or changing the orientation - all these default values can be left out of the code leaving you with `Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter` - everything else in that block can be removed, included the `With` and `End With`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for starters:

```
Option Explicit 'always use this, this helps avoiding typing mistakes in code
Sub MyRoutine()
    'declaration of variables
    Dim colIndex As Long, rowIndex As Long, ws As Worksheet
    colIndex = 13 'M column
    rowIndex = 1 'first row
    'loop through all worksheets
    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 'put your color here
        'do other stuff with the cell, like
        'ws.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value = "some value"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop each sheet of your workbook and apply the color formatting. below is the example code - sets bold property to first cell of every sheet.

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'Do your format here.
    sh.Range("$A$1").Font.Bold = True
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this for you needs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub allsheets()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: while this does correct the OP's issues with object\collection naming, it does not address the issue of changing the color of the specified cell - it would be more appropriate to replace the `value` call with something like `ws.[M1].Interior.Color = vbYellow`

Comment: my intention was to show the op, how to iterate over all sheets, so he can use it for his/her issue. "You can modify this for you needs:"